# Passagem por valor em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tenho dois objetos: A e B:

```
var A={valor:0}
var B={valor:0}
A=B
A.valor=5
console.log(B.valor) // 5
```

gostaria de saber como fazer a passagem por valor, pois o JavaScript passa por referência os objetos, neste exemplo gostaria que `b.valor` ficasse igual a 0;

Comment: Esse exemplo é meio confuso, por que declarar A e B como objetos distintos se você faz `A=B` depois? Qual seria o caso de uso real? Talvez haja outra solução que não requeira cópia do objeto (que é o único jeito de escapar da referência).

Comment: meu exemplo real tem muitas instancias, esse exemplo realmente nao é para uso real, mas acontece exatamente o erro que quero resolver, gostaria de realizar a passagem por valor, e não uma outra solução

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basta utilizar `Object.assign(alvo, obj)`, assim os valores das propriedades do obj serão feitas uma cópia simples (shallow copy).
Exemplo:

```
var A={valor:0, bola: 1}
var B={valor:0, bola: 2}
A = Object.assign({}, B};
A.valor=5
console.log(A) // {valor:5, bola: 2}
console.log(B) // {valor:0, bola: 2}
```

Answer (score 5):

Para `ES5` temos `Object.create()`, que até onde sei, não faz uma cópia exata do elemento e sim define um protótipo do objeto a ser clonado.

Para `ES6` temos, `Object.assign()`, que realmente cria uma cópia...

```
let A={valor:0};
let B={valor:0};
A = Object.assign({},B);
A['valor'] = 5
console.log(A) // 5
console.log(B) // 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Outra solução além do `Object.assign` é converter o objeto em JSON e desconverter na variável que receberá a cópia. A vantagem sobre o assign é que será feita uma cópia profunda. A desvantagem é que só funciona para os tipos de dados que fazem parte do padrão JSON, ou seja, não inclui funções e tipos especiais de objetos.

Exemplo:

```
var original = {a: 1, b: 2};
var copia = JSON.parse(JSON.strinfigy(original));
```

Answer (score 1):

Para referência, minha resposta é similar ao do @Adriano Martins usando o método **[Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)**<sup>1</sup> (ES6), mas passando o valor direto no método:

```js
var A={}
var B={valor:0, valor2:1, valor3:2}
A = Object.assign({}, B, {valor: 5})
console.log(A.valor,B.valor) // retorna 5 0
```

*<sup>1</sup> Não suportado no IE.*

---

Uma forma com maior compatibilidade entre navegadores seria construir um objeto *clone* de **B** com `new Object()`:

```js
var A={}
var B={valor:0, valor2:1, valor3:2}
var novoB = new Object(); // crio o objeto
for(var vals in B){ // importo os valores de B para novoB
   if (B.hasOwnProperty(vals)) novoB[vals] = B[vals];
}
A=B // faço uma cópia de B para A
B=novoB // substituo B por novoB
novoB = null // esvazio o objeto que não servirá mais
A.valor=5, A.valor2=4 // altero os valores de A sem alterar B
console.log(A.valor,B.valor) // retorna: 5 0
console.log(A,B) // retorna A com valores alterados e B intacto
```